# Error installing matplotlib on Windows XP computer

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

I keep getting the following error when I attempt to install matplotlib:

```
raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
valueError: [u' path']
```

I checked out some of the answers here:

[error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat?newreg=a6f44ac611f9493a9948305683ccb183)

Before I had installed VS2008, I tried `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%`because I had VS2010 on my computer.  I uninstalled it and installed VS2008.  I'm running Windows XP on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar issue. Installing from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ has resolved the issue.